# Where can I find the latest software image for an old Google Mini Appliance?

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm trying to bring back to service the Google Mini that I found in our racks.
I managed to login, and found that the software version is `5.0.4`. 
AFAIN, there is already version `7.6`, but we can't download any new software version without access to Google Enterprise support portal, and We can't find the login details...

Any idea where can I find the latest software image (and how to update)?

Thanks in advance!
Gilad

Answer (score 1):

The Google Mini was discontinued about 4 or 5 years ago.  The software version, of the Mini, never went beyond the 5.x series line.

The Google Mini software is no longer available for download as it is no longer supported.  Any legal license to use it would have expired long ago.

The full Google Search Appliance is currently on version 7.6